# Подходит ли в данном случае слово "соответствующего"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, лексикология

> Донбасс располагает богатыми залежами гончарных глин, поэтому возникновение соответствующего ремесла вполне закономерно.

Подходит ли в данном случае слово "соответствующего"? Значения слова я конечно посмотрел, но что-то всё равно не уверен, что они тут подходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово подходит, но вне контекста не вполне ясно, в чём состоит ремесло: в добыче гончарных глин или в собственно гончарном деле.

Comment: А добыча руды это разве ремесло? Тогда бы все рудокопы стали ремеслениками :) Хотя конечно, в широком смысле и круг - квадрат

Comment: гончарном деле так-то